# Write tags from collection to files in amarok

Tags: music, amarok, tag

Sorry if that question is a bit peculiar but is there a way in amarok to have it write back the tags from its database to the files composing its collection?

I ask because on my dual-boot machine windows media player botched the tags of half my music collection and I'd like to write them back from amarok's database without passing through the files one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "tag" you mean [ID3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3), [APE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APE_tag) or [vorbis comments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorbis_comment), then those informations are written **in the file itslef**.
That means that if windows messed with your tags, then Linux (amarok included) can't do anything, unless you have a backup of those files.

My understanding of [Amarok's database](https://userbase.kde.org/Amarok/Manual/Organization/Collection/ExternalDatabase) is that it stores only ratings, statistics, and that sort of information. Not the title, the artist, the album, the year, etc.

To write the tags (anew) for your files in an efficient way, you can try to

- use Amarok system to guess the tags using MusicBrainZ (cf. [this page](https://userbase.kde.org/Amarok/Manual/Organization/TagEditor#Get_Tags_from_MusicBrainz))
- use Amarok system to guess the tags using the file name (cf. [this page](https://userbase.kde.org/Amarok/Manual/Organization/TagEditor#Guess_Tags_From_Filename))
- use a good program to write new tags (cf. [this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4961/101324))

You can always have a peek at `$HOME/.kde/share/apps/amarok/mysqle` to see what your database looks like, but I doubt you're going to find anything useful in it.